# Making a PPM file in C that uses many shapes

Tags: c, ppm

So I'm working on a program that, ultimately, will create a simple image of a spooky pumpkin (square eyes, nose, rectangle mouth).  Right now with my code I am generating a orange circle.  The color of the shape can be changed by inputting an RGB code under the 'Index Through the Image' section, and the shape that is being generated (square, circle, rectangle) can be altered by changing the parameters when the program is run ('./SpookyImageGenerator output.ppm 800 600 100', which creates a circle).

Now... I'm able to generate different shapes and different colors as different PPM files.  How do I go about getting these shapes to generate 'on top of one another' so to speak in the same PPM so I can create an actual image?

This is the code in my main c file that I am using

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MyFunctions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int numRows;            // Number of rows in our image.
    int numCols;            // Number of columns in our image.
    int imageSize;          // The total numberof rows * columns in the image
    int Radius;             // The radius of the circle added to image.
    int row, col;           // The marker to know where we are in the image
    int InOrOut;            // Flag for in or outside of the circle

    unsigned char *outImage;     /* Pixel Pointer           */
    unsigned char *ptr;          /* Pointer                 */
    FILE *outputFP;              /* My out put file pointer */

    printf("=======================================\n");
    printf("        This will make an image        \n");
    printf("=======================================\n");

    // Read in some command line arguments.

    if(argc != 5) {
        printf("Usage: ./[1]SpookyImageMaker [2]OutFile [3]numRows [4]numCols [5]Radius \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((numRows = atoi(argv[2])) <= 0) {
        printf("The given number rows is not positive!\n");
    }
    if((numCols = atoi(argv[3])) <= 0) {
        printf("The given number of columns is not positive!\n");
    }
    if((Radius = atoi(argv[4])) <= 0) {
        printf("Check your radius -- it should be positive!\n");
    }

    printf("=============================================\n");
    printf("        Now working to set up sizes.         \n");
    printf("=============================================\n");

    imageSize = numRows*numCols*3;
    outImage = (unsigned char *) malloc(imageSize);     

    /* Open the image for writing. */
    if ( (outputFP = fopen(argv[1],"w")) == NULL) {
        perror("output open error");
        printf("Error in opening your given output file!\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("=============================================\n");
    printf("        Index Through the given image.       \n");
    printf("=============================================\n");

    ptr = outImage;

    for( row = 0 ; row < numRows ; row++) {
        for( col = 0 ; col < numCols ; col++){
            printf("Row and Col (%d,%d)\n",row,col);
            InOrOut = CheckRadius(numRows, numCols, Radius, row, col);

            if(InOrOut == 1) {
                *ptr     = 255;    // red pixel
                *(ptr+1) = 117;    // green pixel
                *(ptr+2) = 24;     // blue pixel
            } else {
                *ptr     = 0;    // red pixel
                *(ptr+1) = 0;    // green pixel
                *(ptr+2) = 0;    // blue pixel
            }
            // Advance the pixel pointer
            ptr += 3;
        }
    }

    printf("============================================\n");
    printf("   Write it all out to a file for viewing.  \n");
    printf("============================================\n");

    fprintf(outputFP, "P6 %d %d 255\n", numCols, numRows);
    fwrite(outImage, 1, imageSize, outputFP);

    /* Done */
    fclose(outputFP);
    return 0;
}
```

HelperFunctions.c file

```
#include <math.h>                

int CheckRadius(int TotRows, int TotCols, int Radius, int CurPixRow, int CurPixCol){

    int InOrOut   = 0;           // Returns 0 or 1 for out and in side the circle respectively.
    int CenterRow = TotRows/2;   // Place holder for the center with regard to rows.
    int CenterCol = TotCols/2;   // Place holder for the center column.
    int dist      = 0;           // Place in memory for the distance between CurPix and Center.

    // printf("I'm in CheckRadius\n");

    // Compute The distance.
    dist = pow((pow(CenterRow-CurPixRow,2.0)+pow(CenterCol-CurPixCol,2.0)),0.5);

    // Check is dist < Radius and set flag.
    if( dist < Radius){
        InOrOut = 1;
    }

    return InOrOut;
}
```

In addition to this I have HelperFunctions.c file and a MyFunctions.h file, both of which currently only contain a method to CheckRadius of a circle to determine whether a pixel is in or out of a circle.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: For a toy example like this, you could simply add an 'alpha' channel/array (4th value in addition to RGB, in another arr) which determines if an area of an image is visible. Then you could render all shapes to their own buffers, and then sequentially overwrite portions of the base image depending on if they are 'visible' (render pumpkin, render mouth in another buffer, copy only pixels which contain visible mouth on top of the first buffer). Alternatively, you could render each shape to the same buffer, and only write parts of the image which are part of the shape (more efficient, maybe harder

Comment: If you post your full code (helper functions), I might take a shot at an example. Obviously neither of those solutions are the most efficient or 'proper' way of doing rendering. I'm assuming you're doing this more to practice c++ and get familiar with arrays/image representation than write an actual rendering engine

Comment: Updated the question with my helper functions file.  By this point, my plan is to add in some additional if statements and flags under the 'This will make an image' section in the main file, and use a couple of new methods that I'll create in the other class (such as a CheckRadius2).

Comment: So knowing that, I think I'll be able to get multiple shapes together, but not sure on how to move them along the x/y axis (how to get the pumpkins left and right eyes to be in up in their respective corners, and not just overlayed in the middle).

Comment: It's going to come down to math, for positioning the elements. How you want to go about that is up to you. You could position everything relative to some global fixed canvas size, or you could place elements relative to one another. I would start with having a single 'global' canvas buffer, render your pumpkin in the center, and try to add a mouth. That basically involves rendering the mouth lower/adding a vertical offset to it. You can start by dumping a bunch of empty rows on top of it to get it lower relative to the overall image

Comment: Once you have an idea of where you want it, figure out where it is in the overall image, on a scale from 0.0-1.0 on X/Y axis. You can use this and a little math to figure out where it should be rendered in pixel coordinates (`position * max_resolution`, for instance), at which point you have a number of options for implementing that